# Magento - Check for Customer's First Order

Tags: magento

Is there a quick way to programatically check if the currently logged in customer has ever placed an order? I'm writing an observer and at a point I want to simply say

```
if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && (has never placed an order))
{ 
do this 
}
```

possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && (!$orders->getSize()))
{ 
    // has never placed an order 
}
```

The above assumes that you have a `$customer` but if it is not accessible from the event you can usually get the currently logged in customer with:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

Comment: Definitely seems to work, but if we are just trying to get a count, I seem to remember there being a way to just query for that count rather than retrieving a potentially large number of complete objects. At the very least, couldn't you reduce your selected fields down to order_id to minimize network latency?

Comment: @Joseph - `getSize()` uses the internal `getSelectCountSql()` method to retrieve just the count without any paging or limits. The only field requested is `*` so that it becomes `COUNT(*)`. It is the collection's `count()` that load the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create an event?

```
$session = Mage::getModel('customer/session');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$session->getId())->getFirstItem();
```